# csv.reader doesn't work properly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

We are using Google App Engine with Python for our application. I wrote a code that imports users from a CSV file. Here is the code:

```
import csv

users_csv_file = self.request.get("users_csv_file")
csv_reader = csv.reader(users_csv_file)
row_index = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    logging.debug(row_index)
    logging.debug(row)
    .....
    row_index += 1
```

I have 2 CSV files. The first one:

```
"email","name",_activated,is_admin,personal_image,"domain"
test_1@example.com,"Mark Gates",true,true,http://www.google.com.au/test,hello.world.com
test_2@example.com,"Bill Zuck Junior 1",false,false,"",""
test_3@example.com,"Bill Zuck Junior 2",false,false,"",""
```

And the second one:

```
email,name,_activated,is_admin,personal_image,domain
test_1@example.com,Mark Gates,TRUE,TRUE,http://www.google.com.au/test,hello.world.com
test_2@example.com,Bill Zuck Junior 1,FALSE,FALSE,,
test_3@example.com,Bill Zuck Junior 2,FALSE,FALSE,,
```

But the problem is, with the first CSV file the first row is `['email']`, and with the second CSV file the first row is `['e']`. I want the row to be a list of all the values in this row. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the data you have, the CSV reader should work fine. If you are getting a string, then you can convert this to a file type stream using the `StringIO` module as follows:

```
import csv, StringIO

users_csv_file = StringIO.StringIO(self.request.get("users_csv_file"))
csv_reader = csv.reader(users_csv_file)

for row_index, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
    logging.debug(row_index)
    logging.debug(row)
    .....
```

Also, you can use the `enumerate` function to automatically provide your `row_index`.

If you are using Python 3, you would need the following tweak:

```
import io

users_csv_file = io.StringIO(self.request.get("users_csv_file"))
```